# Renaming received file uploaded from multipart/form-data (request,"c:/")

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload, multipartform-data

I have a jsp code to upload a file from multipart/form-data..

upload.jsp

```
 <%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
 <%@page import="com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest" %>
 <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
 <%
try
   {
    MultipartRequest mrequest = new MultipartRequest(request, "C:/uploads");
    String file_name=mrequest.getParameter("fname");//recieve fname
    Enumeration files = mrequest.getFileNames();

    while(files.hasMoreElements() )
      {
        String upload = (String)files.nextElement();
         String filename = mrequest.getFilesystemName(upload);
        System.out.println(filename);
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
System.out.println("Error creating file: " + ex );
}%>
```

test.html

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<FORM ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" ACTION="upload.jsp" METHOD="POST">
choose file  <input type="file" name="file">
name for file <input type="text" name="fname">
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</FORM>
</BODY>
```

This code works and uploads file to `c:/upload` directory. But what if we want to change the name of file while uploading to the name other than its original name that receive from form. How can it be done, **as it receives the original filename as an enumeration**?

Comment: There are many similar questions on SO alredy.
'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet'
Or even 'http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_file_uploading.htm'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code like this .

```
while(files.hasMoreElements())
{
    String upload=(String)files.nextElement();

    File filename=new File(mrequest.getOriginalFileName(upload));

    filename.renameTo("newName");
}
```

in the place of newName give your desired value :)